# Data/Structure Validation (for R)

Tags: r, validation, command-line, analysis

My internet search was unsuccessful, therefore I hope that somebody got an idea on this. Assume I collaborate with a colleague and we work with a dataset. He preprocesses data which I read into R.

What I am looking for is a tool for the command line or a package in R which I can use to define a data format, e.g., something like this:

```
data description

date:    date
age:     positive integer
weight:  positive float
job:     string, NA
```

Then, I would like to check the validity of a given dataset, either on the command line or in R. Nice to have, but not necessary: Generating test data from a given data structure description.

Thank you for your ideas/hints!

Comment: Can you use a database?

Comment: I could, however, if I had the possibility to choose, I would prefer a solution independent of the data storage.

Comment: Get classes and compare with your description: `identical(sapply(mydata,class),myDescription` ? Maybe [wakefield](https://github.com/trinker/wakefield) package is relevant to create dummy datasets.

Comment: @Xiphias I preapred an answer ( a good one I think), unfortunaltly the question was closed before I can post it. I don't konw if we can reopen it again.

Comment: @Xiphias here a [gist](https://gist.github.com/agstudy/b93ad037715f80848f35) where I post an answer.

Comment: Thank you! I voted for reopening, but there have to be more votes, I suppose.

Comment: @Xiphias , let me know if the answer in the gist is clear for you.